# How to navigate to a url in class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-hooks, react-router-dom

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
export class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        window.data_login_callback = this.data_login_callback
        this.data_login_callback = this.data_login_callback.bind(this);
    }
    state = { brand: "" }
rend(props){
    console.log("ddd",props)
}
data_login_callback(response) {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/google_login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
 "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(response),
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        if (json.status === "OK") {
            <Link to={json.Redirect}></Link> //want to redirect this but not working
            }
        });      
    }
    render() {  
        return (
           <div className="google-sign-in-btn">
                <div id="g_id_onload"
                    data-client_id="********************"
                    data-context="signin"
                    data-ux_mode="popup"
                    data-callback="data_login_callback"
                    data-auto_prompt="false">
                </div>
                <div class="g_id_signin"
                    data-type="standard"
                    data-shape="rectangular"
                    data-theme="outline"
                    data-text="signin_with"
                 `  data-size="large"
                    data-logo_alignment="left">
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

i have tried useNavigate ,link,redirect and many things of react but cannot use them in react class component but cannot navigate to a link , json.redirect in data_login_callback contains the link to which i want to get redirected.not able to pass navigate in render since json.redirect is null there and not able to use state in that

Comment: You can access the history object from the component's props

Comment: Change <Link to={json.Redirect}></Link> to <Redirect to={json.Redirect}/>; You already imported it

Answer (score 1):

The `Link` component must be rendered in order to clicked on to effect any navigation action, simply returning it from an asynchronous callback won't work. You will need to access either the `history` object `if using` react-router-dom@5`or below, or the`navigate`function`if using `react-router-dom@6` and up.

Using the `useHistory` (RRDv5) or `useNavigate` (RRDv6) are the easiest ways to do this, but React hooks can only be used in React function components. Normally I wouldn't cover this conversion but since the `Login` component code is simple enough I'll recommend conversion in order to use React hooks.

If using `react-router-dom@5`:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [brand, setBrand] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    data_login_callback(response) {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/google_login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(response),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log(json);
          if (json.status === "OK") {
            history.push(json.Redirect);
          }
        });      
    }

    window.data_login_callback = data_login_callback;

    return () => {
      window.data_login_callback = undefined;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="google-sign-in-btn">
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="********************"
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="popup"
        data-callback="data_login_callback"
        data-auto_prompt="false"
      >
      </div>
      <div
        class="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-theme="outline"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      >
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If using `react-router-dom@6`:

```
import { useNavigtate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [brand, setBrand] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    data_login_callback(response) {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/google_login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(response),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log(json);
          if (json.status === "OK") {
            navigate(json.Redirect);
          }
        });      
    }

    window.data_login_callback = data_login_callback;

    return () => {
      window.data_login_callback = undefined;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="google-sign-in-btn">
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="********************"
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="popup"
        data-callback="data_login_callback"
        data-auto_prompt="false"
      >
      </div>
      <div
        class="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-theme="outline"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      >
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If conversion isn't your thing and you prefer to stick to outdated React class components, then you can inject either `history` or `navigate` as a prop.

If using RRDv5, import the `withRouter` Higher Order Component and access `this.props.history`.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    window.data_login_callback = this.data_login_callback
    this.data_login_callback = this.data_login_callback.bind(this);
  }

  state = { brand: "" }

  data_login_callback(response) {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/google_login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(response),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        if (json.status === "OK") {
          this.props.history.push(json.Redirect);
        }
      });      
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <div className="google-sign-in-btn">
        <div
          id="g_id_onload"
          data-client_id="********************"
          data-context="signin"
          data-ux_mode="popup"
          data-callback="data_login_callback"
          data-auto_prompt="false"
        >
        </div>
        <div
          class="g_id_signin"
          data-type="standard"
          data-shape="rectangular"
          data-theme="outline"
          data-text="signin_with"
          data-size="large"
          data-logo_alignment="left"
        >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

If using RRDv6, you'll have to roll your own [`withRouter` HOC](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) since it was removed.

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

export const withRouter = (Component) => (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();

  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      router={{ location, navigate, params }}
    />
  );
};
```

```
import { withRouter } from '../path/to/withRouter';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    window.data_login_callback = this.data_login_callback
    this.data_login_callback = this.data_login_callback.bind(this);
  }

  state = { brand: "" }

  data_login_callback(response) {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/google_login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(response),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        if (json.status === "OK") {
          this.props.router.navigate(json.Redirect);
        }
      });      
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <div className="google-sign-in-btn">
        <div
          id="g_id_onload"
          data-client_id="********************"
          data-context="signin"
          data-ux_mode="popup"
          data-callback="data_login_callback"
          data-auto_prompt="false"
        >
        </div>
        <div
          class="g_id_signin"
          data-type="standard"
          data-shape="rectangular"
          data-theme="outline"
          data-text="signin_with"
          data-size="large"
          data-logo_alignment="left"
        >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Drew Reese's answer more but the quickest way is to fix this without switching off from a class component is to change this:

```
<Link to={json.Redirect}></Link>
```

to

```
<Redirect to={json.Redirect}/>
```

You already imported it, but just didn't use it.

Answer (score -2):

In your code you made something that seems not to be the correct action, you returned a react component in case the request was ok and you want to navigate the user to some other screen, okay.

returning a Link component in that case won't do anything at all.

React Router provides a **redirect** utility that will redirect a user to a certain destination and it should work fine.

something that worth to mention that React Router's offical docs recommends use
**redirect** over **navigate** from useNavigate hook in terms of dealing with HTTPs requests or dealing with loaders.
refer the offical docs for furthermore details https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect

I hope I helped you and please leave any comment if any of my talk wasn't clear enough

Comment: i used useNavigate but it is not working it is saying cannot use rect hooks in class componet

Comment: that's right, I was saying it as a tip, but surely you cannot use React hooks inside of class components, now you can use redirect utility and see what will happen!

Comment: You can render the `<Redirect to='/somewhere'/>;` component to redirect in a class component

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example of how to use the utility you are suggesting. I feel like the answer may be correct, but is incomplete as is

Comment: `Redirect` would work as you described only if it is rendered in the DOM but in his case, he returned it but didn't render it in the DOM so it won't work...do you want me to edit the answer with a code that demonstrates the answer?